# Stop vibrations (API level 26 and above)

Tags: android

Is there a way to stop/cancel vibrations for API level 26 and above?

Currently, I am using foreground services since I don't want my program to stop (and from API level 26 and above, there are time restrictions for background services). However, since then my vibrations don't seem to cancel as before (API 25 cancels as I would expect).

How can I accomplish this, preferably without using `JobScheduler`?